# dplyr: Filter within groups based on multiple closest values

Tags: r, dplyr

Think I'm missing something simple here and looked through lots of examples on slicing and filtering using dplyr. I have a vector, sepals, that I want to use to subset a larger data set:

`sepals=c(4:7)`

It is easy to filter based on exact match:

`iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length %in% sepals)`

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
 1            5         3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa    
 2            5         3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa    
 3            5         3            1.6         0.2 setosa    
 4            5         3.4          1.6         0.4 setosa    
 5            5         3.2          1.2         0.2 setosa    
 6            5         3.5          1.3         0.3 setosa    
 7            5         3.5          1.6         0.6 setosa    
 8            5         3.3          1.4         0.2 setosa    
 9            7         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
10            5         2            3.5         1   versicolor
11            6         2.2          4           1   versicolor
12            6         2.9          4.5         1.5 versicolor
```

But really I want to match the closest values to the vector sepals for each species, which is fine if I take the elements one at a time:

`iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% filter(abs(Sepal.Length-4)==min(abs(Sepal.Length-4)))`

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
1          4.3         3            1.1         0.1 setosa    
2          4.9         2.4          3.3         1   versicolor
3          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7 virginica
```

Same results can be obtained more concisely from the following:

`iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% slice(which.min(abs(Sepal.Length-4)))` or,
`iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% slice_min(abs(Sepal.Length-4))`

Where 4 is the first element in the vector sepals. My trouble is getting the operation to work over the whole vector sepals:

`iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% slice(which.min(abs(Sepal.Length-sepals)))`

gives erroneous results and errors:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
1          5           3            1.6         0.2 setosa    
2          5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor
3          6           3            4.8         1.8 virginica 
Warning messages:
1: In Sepal.Length - sepals :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Similarly problematic:

`iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% slice_min(abs(Sepal.Length-sepals))`

`iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% filter(abs(Sepal.Length-sepals)==min(abs(Sepal.Length-sepals)))`

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: The logic is not clear. What do you mean by "match the closest values to the vector sepals". How do you measure "proximity" to a numeric vector?

Comment: From a vector of values c(3.99, 4.1, 4.2, 5, 5.1, 7), which is "closer" to the vector (5:7)?

Comment: I think u can use map_df or map_dbl function from library purrr packages to get your desire results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like I_O's use of near_anyof, but here is a proposal based closely on your initial approach where you hand code a check against '4' (of the 4-7 values you want to repeat) where I should how to construct the repetition programmatically.

```
library(tidyverse)

sepals <- 4:7

(myresults <- map_dfr(
  sepals,
  \(spl){
    iris |>
      group_by(Species) |>
      slice(which.min(abs(Sepal.Length - spl))) |> ungroup()
  }
))
```

note that I'm preferring the more modern pipe `|>` but you can use the same code with magrittr pipe `%>%` if you have to

Comment: Nice! You could also just `slice( ..., .by = Species)` . Downside: slightly harder for someone else to reproduce the code's intention.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
library(dplyr)

sepals <- 4:7

near_anyof <- Vectorize(near) ## see ?near

result <- 
  iris |>
  rowwise() |>
  filter(near_anyof(Sepal.Length, sepals,
                    tol = 0.1 ## your allowable tolerance here
         ) |> 
         any()
         )
```

check:

```
count(result, Sepal.Length)

## # A tibble: 9 x 2
## # Rowwise: 
##   Sepal.Length     n
##          <dbl> <int>
## 1          4.9     6
## 2          5      10
## 3          5.1     9
## 4          5.9     3
## 5          6       6
## 6          6.1     6
## 7          6.9     4
## 8          7       1
## 9          7.1     1
```

Comment: Nice code too thanks, Nir's interpretation on desired final structure was right on. Appreciate the opportunity to learn from you both .